# Kubernetes - Perform rolling update with Golang plugin

Tags: curl, go, kubernetes

I have a **docker** in **kubernetes** that **listen** to **configMap** changes and trigger a **golang** function every change.

I want to perform `rolling-update` to **deployment** in this part and i didn't find any **api** that have this command.

Is there anyone who know an **api** with this command?
Or know a better way to get to the same result?

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment and https://github.com/appscode/kloader already?

Comment: i didn't found the command i looking for

Comment: It's in the first link, please do put a little bit of effort into it ...

Comment: To be more precise https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/ and look for **Updating a Deployment**

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I'm new with kubernetes. I saw that the 'update' function require param called in this case 'result' that came from create as return value. I didn't understand if there is a way to just update (like refresh) the deployment without sending params, and more important - to make sure it's happens with rolling-update

Comment: @Rod This is the way to do it with kubectl. In my golang pod there is no kubectl installed.

Comment: OIC @Evya2005 I assumed you're familiar with K8S. So yes, rolling update is the default so this will work as expected. Also, if you have an existing deployment, just skip the creation part and use [List](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go#L133) to fetch it.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Do u mean i can call List and then find my deployment in the list and send it to 'update' as param? instead of 'result' ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what in mean.